# Property of natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can every integer be written as 
$$N=\prod _{ n=1 }^{ n=k }{ { (a }_{ n } } { x }_{ n }+{ b }_{ n }{ y }_{ n })$$
where

1)$(a_n,b_n )$are coprime

2)$( a_n,b_n,k)$ are any (random) integers

3)$( x_n,y_n )$  belong to a specific class of infinite integers

Comment: I am at a loss how to use mathematical notations. Do let me know how to do it):

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to do it, because it's hard to figure out what you are trying to write!

Comment: It's a terrible omission in this site that there's no clear section where to refer newbies to learn the rather easy basic rules of writing mathematics with LaTeX...a pity, indeed.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @DonAntonio:  The help section now includes http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation but the user has to click through.  On meta, there is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto which is much better

Comment: If you guys could figure out the question I have posted,can you edit it..please ):

Comment: @HashirOmer, you better go to one of the links above and learn how to do it by yourself. I, for one, cannot understand what you wrote.

Comment: @HashirOmer: Another hint: You also can write your question in a paper, scan it, and attach its image in the text, by means of text editor buttons (above of the box you just made your question post).

Comment: @RR, one may need more points than OP has to attach images.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:These comments are about to help OP to tell us his question. I guess the main problem is this!